# Spinner only on form submit

Tags: javascript, dom

I would like to show a spinner only after a form has been submitted. How can I achieve this? I have tried using a boolean variable that is stored in the `sessionStorage` and modified only when the form is submitted and is located at the window load event but the spinner is never shown. The variable dictates whether the spinner is shown or not:

```
window.addEventListener("load", function () {
   if (sessionStorage.getItem("submitted") === "true") {
      // display spinner here
   }
});
```

Kindly provide a vanilla js solution not jQuery, Angular etc...

Comment: You need to show a [mcve] that shows how you set the session storage, and probably also how you show the spinner, with the relevant HTML code.

Answer (score 0):

If `sessionStorage.getItem("submitted")` is a boolean value, it's not `"true"` but just `true` without the quotes.

```
sessionStorage.getItem("submitted") === true
```

Comment: I am creating a form and the ```onsubmit``` attribute has a form validation boolean method. At the end of the method, as long as none of the invalid inputs have returned ```false```, the ```sessionStorage``` variable is to be updated to ```true``` so that upon loading the page again the variable will be rechecked. Why is the variable still ```false``` even after none of the inputs returned ```false```? Keep in mind that the form ```action``` attribute leads to the same page (form page).

Comment: Without reading your code, I can't tell why it doesn't work.

Comment: Do you have any other way to show the spinner without using sessionStorage?